# How to Convert Hex to Double C#?

Tags: c#

i have hex data  "44 34 00 00" , and i'll Convert to double "720.0" using C#

like this..

[image]

anyone can help? thanks..

Comment: you want to convert hex to double ?

Comment: `double` is 8-byte size. Do you mean `float`?

Comment: Have you even tried **anything**? E.g. looking if anyone already solved this problem before?

Comment: i try using  double result = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(0x44340000); but result is 5.65338844455775E-315  not  720.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is the bytes from a Single (aka `float`), so do this:

```
double result = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(0x44340000), 0);
Console.WriteLine(result); // Prints 720
```

Answer (score 0):

check that 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.int64bitstodouble

BitConverter example:

double d = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(0xdeadbeef);